# ReactNative 0.57 build IOS Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined (null))

Tags: react-native

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0YVC.jpg)

[Error log on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpnxc.jpg)

package.json code

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/events": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.5",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.56.23",
    "@types/react-native-drawer-layout": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.21",
    "antd-mobile-rn": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.9.1",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "mobx": "4.3.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.8",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.18",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-navigation": "^2.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add some more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .babelrc file it must have something like this

`{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}`